# What's the difference between solc's --opcodes and --asm?

Tags: solidity

I'm leanring low-level Solidity inline assembly, but confused by different output formats.

The ouptut option of Solidity compiler says:

```
  --asm                EVM assembly of the contracts.
  --opcodes            Opcodes of the contracts.
```

I tried both options to compile the contract below:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.4.16 <0.9.0;

contract MyContract {
    string bar = "Hello World";

    function foo() public view returns(string memory) {
        return bar;
    }
}
```

The command `solc -o output --asm contract.sol` generated MyContract.evm:

```
    /* "contract.sol":70:208  contract MyContract {... */
  mstore(0x40, 0x80)
    /* "contract.sol":96:122  string bar = "Hello World" */
  mload(0x40)
  dup1
  0x40
  add
  0x40
  mstore
  dup1
  0x0b
  dup2
  mstore
  0x20
  add
  0x7657399374655890603765000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  dup2
  mstore
  pop
  0x00
  swap1
  dup1
  mload
  swap1
  0x20
  add
  swap1
  tag_1
  swap3
  swap2
  swap1
  tag_2
  jump  // in
tag_1:
  pop
    /* "contract.sol":70:208  contract MyContract {... */
  callvalue
  dup1
... (and a lot more code)
```

The command `solc -o output --opcodes contract.sol` generated MyContract.opcode:

```
PUSH1 0x80 PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD DUP1 PUSH1 0x40 ADD PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE DUP1 PUSH1 0xB DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 ADD PUSH32 0x7657399374655890603765000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 DUP2 MSTORE POP PUSH1 0x0 SWAP1 DUP1 MLOAD SWAP1 PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP1 PUSH2 0x4F SWAP3 SWAP2 SWAP1 PUSH2 0x62 JUMP JUMPDEST POP CALLVALUE DUP1 ISZERO PUSH2 0x5C JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST POP PUSH2 0x166 JUMP JUMPDEST DUP3 DUP1 SLOAD PUSH2 0x6E SWAP1 PUSH2 0x105 JUMP JUMPDEST SWAP1 PUSH1 0x0 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 PUSH1 0x0 KECCAK256 SWAP1 PUSH1 0x1F ADD PUSH1 0x20 SWAP1 DIV DUP2 ADD SWAP3 DUP3 PUSH2 0x90 JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP6 SSTORE PUSH2 0xD7 JUMP JUMPDEST DUP3 PUSH1 0x1F LT PUSH2 0xA9 JUMPI DUP1 MLOAD PUSH1 ... ...
```

They look pretty much similar, although not 100% matching each other...

**Questions**

1. Does `--opcodes` just give a more compact form of assembly code compared to `--asm` output?
2. `PUSH1 0x80 PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE` in `--opcodes` format vs.  `mstore(0x40, 0x80)` in `--asm` format. Are they doing the same thing? (I guess so but not 100% sure...)
3. Is there a way to print `--opcodes` in a pretty format rather than in a single line?
4. Are there any good resouces to learn Solidity inline assembly? I googled around but found a bunch of one page blogs, which are good to explain the basics but unfortunately none of them gives a complete and in-depth tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered in the StackOverflow community.
Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67114046/whats-the-difference-between-solcs-opcodes-and-asm) for the answers.